# Null values sql join in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am doing this query

```
SELECT m.chat_id, m.msg_sender_id, m.message, m.id,
       DATE_FORMAT(m.created_at, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') as created_at,
       g.id as group_id, g.name as group_name, g.image as group_image
FROM message as m 
INNER JOIN chat as c ON c.id = m.chat_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN group as g ON c.group_id = g.id
WHERE c.id = 434
ORDER BY m.id ASC
```

What I want to achieve is to get all messages from chat and if there is a group involved in chat to return group. Group is attached to chat object (not to message object). I am getting `group` on all rows for some reason.

Can you advice how can I achieve this?

`============= EDIT ==============`

`group` table structure looks like this:

```
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `image` longtext COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `creator_id` int(11) NOT NULL
```

`chat` table structure looks like this

```
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `group_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `person1_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `invitation_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
```

`message` table looks like this

```
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `message` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `created_at` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `chat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `msg_sender_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
```

This is the result from a query

```
434 14  Some text   900 2017-09-10 09:48:56 3   My group 1  image.jpg
434 13  Some text 2 901 2017-09-10 09:48:59 3   My group 1  image.jpg
434 14  Some text 3 935 2017-09-16 15:37:07 3   My group 1  image.jpg
434 14  Some text 4 968 2017-09-21 06:52:56 3   My group 1  image.jpg
```

Comment: I don't really understand the problem. Your query seems fine, but you are getting more results from `group_group` than expected? Please add some sample data.

Comment: There's no `group` here.

Comment: Probably you have the id=434 present in all the three tables including group hence you are getting groupName for all rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.

Your query is correct as written.  You have an `inner join` for `chat` and `messages`.  You have a `left outer join` for `group`.

I think you may be misinterpreting the result set.  The result set is a table with *all* columns for each row.  You don't get some columns for messages and then other columns for chats.  That is how SQL works.

Alternatively, your queries orders by by `m.id`.  Perhaps this ordering happens to bring all the messages with groups to the top.

Comment: Thanks, it was my structuring mistake. It shows group in all rows since all chats have group attached.